# Communication between Android and bluetooth devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'd like to connect the Android application and sensors with bluetooth and display sensor data on the application, but I do not know where to change.

Is the data of the sensor stored in the character stick?
If so, how do you display the stored data?

The equipment you are using is the SONY MESH button.
Android ver 5.0.2
Android Studio ver 2.3.1

MainActivity.java

```
private final static int SDKVER_LOLLIPOP = 21;
private final static int MESSAGE_NEW_RECEIVEDNUM = 0;
private final static int MESSAGE_NEW_SENDNUM = 1;
private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 123456;
private BluetoothManager mBleManager;
private BluetoothAdapter mBleAdapter;
private boolean mIsBluetoothEnable = false;
private BluetoothLeScanner mBleScanner;
private BluetoothGatt mBleGatt;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mBleCharacteristic;
private TextView mTxtReceivedNum;
private TextView mTxtSendNum;
private String meshdata = String.valueOf(0x00020103);
private String mStrReceivedNum = "";
private String mStrSendNum = "";


private static final String SERVICE_UUID = "72C90001-57A9-4D40-B746-534E22EC9F9E";

private static final String CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "72C90003-57A9-4D40-B746-534E22EC9F9E";

private static final String CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";


private Random mRandom = new Random();
private Timer mTimer;
private SendDataTimer mSendDataTimer;

private final LeScanCallback mScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mBleGatt = device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, mGattCallback);
            }
        });
    }
};
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState)
    {

        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {

            gatt.discoverServices();
        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {

            if (mBleGatt != null)
            {
                mBleGatt.close();
                mBleGatt = null;
            }
            mIsBluetoothEnable = false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status)
    {

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

            BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString(SERVICE_UUID));
            if (service != null)
            {

                mBleCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID));

                if (mBleCharacteristic != null) {

                    mBleGatt = gatt;


                    boolean registered = mBleGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(mBleCharacteristic, true);


                    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = mBleCharacteristic.getDescriptor(
                            UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID));

                    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                    mBleGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

                    mIsBluetoothEnable = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
    {

        if (CHARACTERISTIC_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid().toString().toUpperCase()))
        {

            mStrReceivedNum = characteristic.getStringValue(0);

            mBleHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_NEW_RECEIVEDNUM);
        }
    }
};
private Handler mBleHandler = new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {

        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case MESSAGE_NEW_RECEIVEDNUM:
                mTxtReceivedNum.setText(mStrReceivedNum);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_NEW_SENDNUM:
                mTxtSendNum.setText(mStrSendNum);
                break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mIsBluetoothEnable = false;


    mTxtReceivedNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.received_num);
    mTxtSendNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.send_num);


    mBleManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBleAdapter = mBleManager.getAdapter();


    mTimer = new Timer();
    mSendDataTimer = new SendDataTimer();

    mTimer.schedule(mSendDataTimer, 500, 1000);


    if ((mBleAdapter == null)
            || (! mBleAdapter.isEnabled())) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
    else
    {

        this.scanNewDevice();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            if ((mBleAdapter != null)
                    || (mBleAdapter.isEnabled())) {

                this.scanNewDevice();
            }
            break;
    }
}
private void scanNewDevice()
{

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= SDKVER_LOLLIPOP)
    {
        this.startScanByBleScanner();
    }
    else
    {

        mBleAdapter.startLeScan(mScanCallback);
    }
}
@TargetApi(SDKVER_LOLLIPOP)
private void startScanByBleScanner()
{
    mBleScanner = mBleAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

    mBleScanner.startScan(new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);

            result.getDevice().connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, mGattCallback);
        }
        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int intErrorCode)
        {
            super.onScanFailed(intErrorCode);
        }
    });
}
public class SendDataTimer extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(mIsBluetoothEnable)
        {

            mStrSendNum = String.valueOf(mRandom.nextInt(1000));

            mBleHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_NEW_SENDNUM);

            mBleCharacteristic.setValue(meshdata);
            mBleGatt.writeCharacteristic(mBleCharacteristic);
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{

    mIsBluetoothEnable = false;
    if(mBleGatt != null) {
        mBleGatt.close();
        mBleGatt = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Related places

```
@Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
    {

        if (CHARACTERISTIC_UUID.equals(characteristic.getUuid().toString().toUpperCase()))
        {

            mStrReceivedNum = characteristic.getStringValue(0);

            mBleHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_NEW_RECEIVEDNUM);
        }
    }
```

Related places

```
    private Handler mBleHandler = new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {

        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case MESSAGE_NEW_RECEIVEDNUM:
                mTxtReceivedNum.setText(mStrReceivedNum);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_NEW_SENDNUM:
                mTxtSendNum.setText(mStrSendNum);
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Related places

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mIsBluetoothEnable = false;


    mTxtReceivedNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.received_num);
    mTxtSendNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.send_num);
```

Related places

```
public class SendDataTimer extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(mIsBluetoothEnable)
        {

            mStrSendNum = String.valueOf(mRandom.nextInt(1000));

            mBleHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_NEW_SENDNUM);

            mBleCharacteristic.setValue(mStrSendNum);
            mBleGatt.writeCharacteristic(mBleCharacteristic);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/received_num"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:gravity="right"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/send_num"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You have provided your code, which is good, but it's a lot of code for someone to review to help with your question.  Please read [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Related place added.